# Android project structure

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an issue that the project structure is different between original project and modified project. After I removed ZXing library from original project which is a left hand side from the image, I realized that the color of files in Gradle Scripts were changed from black to orange and blue. Also the color of the packages in java section were changed from black to orange. What does changing color mean in Android Studio ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your MCL project has Version Control enabled for it. What this means is that the files could be uploaded to your remote Github repo if you have one.

Orange means the files won't be added if you make a commit. Aka, they're unversioned, or untracked.

Blue means the files have been modified since the last Pull from the remote repo.

Black means the files haven't been touched since the last Pull from the remote repo.

And finally, Green means the files are new, and are being tracked by VCS. If you make a commit, green files will be uploaded to your remote repo.

To add all your files (and make the Orange go away), select the root folder (MCL-MCL) in your project pane, and press Control+Alt+A.

Answer (score 0):

Your version control shows that some changes happened in your package. Look into the official documentation here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/file-status-highlights.html